# awk output not working inside bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I've tested the following line in terminal and it works perfectly:

```
zcat file_2016_01_01.gz | awk 'BEGIN { FS= "|"}; {if ($1 =="START" && $7 == "1234") {flag=1}} flag ; {if ($1=="STOP"){flag=0}}'> exit.txt
```

but when I try to automate the extraction for several files in a bash script the output files are empty:

Updated Code:    the for loops were commented for showing that it wasn't the problem

```
#!/bin/bash
REF="ref"
CODE="code"
REP="path_to_file"
#for m in 0{1..3}
#do
#  for d in 0{1..9} {10..31};
#  do
#    DATE="2016_${m}_${d}"
DATE="2016_01_04"

EXIT=${REF}_${CODE}_${DATE}.gz
if [ -e $REP/file_$DATE.gz ]
    then
            zcat $REP/file_$DATE.gz | awk 'BEGIN { FS= "|"}; {if ($1 =="START" && $7 == "'"$CODE"'" && $18== "'"$REF"'") {flag=1}} flag ; {if ($1=="STOP"){flag=0}} ' > $EXIT
    else
            echo "File not found!"
fi
#  done
#done
exit 0
```

could anybody help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/ found your immediate bug, and several others, automatically. Consider running your code through it before getting humans involved in the future.

Comment: I saw the comments of spellchecker and there wasn't any actual problem in the code, nevertheless I updated the code with a version that "pass" the spell checker.

Comment: Your code is still buggy as-given -- they turn off some warnings when the values that could trigger bugs are given as constants that don't. This is a place where I somewhat disagree with @koalaman (its maintainer). `[ -e "$REP/file_$DATE.gz" ]` needs to be quoted; `zcat "$REP/file_$DATE.gz"` needs quotes likewise.

Comment: If instead of `REP="path_to_file"` you had `REP=$1`, then shellcheck (which is "static checking", not "spell checking") would properly show warnings regarding how that value is expanded -- specifically, [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086).

Comment: As for "the for loops were commented showing that that wasn't the problem" -- `DATE="2016_$m_$d"` will **always** expand `$m_`, not `$m`. There is no conceivable way that line could have been correct as it was originally written.

Comment: ...anyhow, bringing us back to point -- amend your question to show what your current script does when run with `bash -x`, and compare that with what you want/expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to be here:

```
DATE="2016_$m_$d"
```

Since `_` is considered part of variable name it is effectively making it:

```
DATE="2016_${m_}${d}"
```

Since you don't have a variable named `$m_`, effectively you will be getting the value of `"2016_$d"` in your `DATE` variable.

You can fix it by using:

```
DATE="2016_${m}_${d}"
```

Also recommended to check your script on shellcheck.net to find and fix other obvious mistakes.

Comment: In order to prove if that was the problem I remove the for loops and write a single date DATE="2016_01_04". And the output file is still empty. PS: I did the spellcheck thanks

Comment: is in the main question

Comment: Run your script using `bash -x script.sh` and see output of each step. This will help you find which command is failing.

Comment: thanks I was able to see the problem with the -x option